# Existence of some differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $x f_x=f_y$. How can I prove that there is a differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=g(xe^y)$?

It's clear for me that the gradient of this function is orthogonal to the vector $(x,-1)$. Can I somehow deduce from this that $f$ is constant on $xe^y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ be two points in $\mathbb R^2$ so that $y_1 < y_2$ and
$$x_1 e^{y_1} = x_2 e^{y_2} =: C.$$
Consider 
$$h(t) = f\left(Ce^{-t}, t\right), t\in [y_1, y_2] .$$
Then

$$h'(t) = -f_x(Ce^{-t}, t) Ce^{-t} + f_y( Ce^{-t}, t) = 0$$
as $x f_x =f_y $. Thus $h(t)$ is a constant function and so 
$$\tag{1} f\left(x_1, y_1\right) = f(x_2, y_2).$$
Define $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, where 
$$\tag{2} g(t) = f(t, 0).$$
For all $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$, using $(1)$ (setting $(x_1, y_1) = (xe^y,0)$ and $(x_2 , y_2) = (x, y)$), 
$$g(xe^y) = f(xe^y,0) = f(x, y).$$
From $(2)$, $g$ is differentiable.